# Safari 100% height and width exception

Tags: iphone, css, safari, responsive-design, media-queries

I've got a logo that I want to resize to full width and relative height using media queries which works fine in (almost) every browser except Safari.

Safari renders the image over the whole screen instead of keeping the aspect ratio.

My HTML

```
<div id="logo"><a href="http://www.stilundso.de/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-h-c-200-206-2.jpg" width="200" height="206"></a></div>
```

My CSS

```
div#logo {background:#fff; width:200px; border-right:1px solid #FFF; height:206px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-top:41px;}

@media only screen and (max-width:206px) {
    div#logo {display:block; position:static; padding:0; border-right:none; width:auto; height:auto;}
    div#logo img {height:100%; width:100%;}
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXgBB/1/).

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

It works on Safari now but not in Safari on my iPhone 3G. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `height:auto;` instead which I find works just as well and doesn't cause this issue in Safari.

Comment: Ok, now I feel kind of stupid. I didnt even try it because in developer tools it was stroked out as if it's being overwritten by the img height and width html attributes.

Comment: Don't feel stupid! I've had this issue in the past on iOS devices and found that this fixed it perfectly.