# Responsive image not going to 100% width in Safari (fine in Chrome)

Tags: html, css, safari

On my website I use media queries to resize elements based on device size. This works fine and elements do resize perfectly fine in any browser (Chrome, Safari, whatever).

I have one big issue though, and that is that I have a logo img tag that starts with automatic width and then, when on mobile (the media query works fine, it does react and apply styles) it's supposed to go to 100% width so it takes up the whole line. This works superbly in Chrome and Firefox, but it does not work in Safari.

Using Safari dev tools I can see that it is in fact applying 100% width to the element, but it doesn't actually compute 100% width of the viewport, but rather some other number (not sure where it's coming from).

So essentially the issue is that in Safari (and only in Safari) when I try to responsively apply 100% width to elements it doesn't work properly. It is applied but is not actually the full viewport width.

I have my viewport meta tag and whatever, but this is happening on desktop and mobile Safari, so I doubt that is it.

Any ideas?

I shall share some code:

```css
.Logo
  width: 100%
  margin-top: 3em
  margin-bottom: 2em
  display: block
  text-align: center

  @media (min-width: mobile-nav-break)
    margin-bottom: 3em
    text-align: left
    margin: 0
    flex: 1

  img
    height: 3em
```

That is my logo's CSS. It's in Stylus, but it renders to what you would expect it to render to. It looks fine in Chrome in any size (also below the breakpoint).

The "duplicate question" is not a duplicate at all. In my case the logo is not supposed to be auto scaling, only it's container should go to 100%.

Comment: Did you try adding : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` to your HTML ? I suppose you do since you mentioned it, is it possible to share some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari 100% height and width exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675153/safari-100-height-and-width-exception)

Comment: Which part of your scenario is related to C language?

Comment: @Gerhardh None, what kind of question is that?

Comment: @daan.desmedt As I mentioned in my question, I have a proper viewport tag.

<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />

Comment: aFreshMelon: It's a "why do you spam with wrong tags" question. You added a C tag to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Add this meta tag to your head. meta name viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```